# Vectors question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, geometry

I am stuck on this vectors question I have for home work. Does anything think they can help point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

An explorer is caught in a whiteout (in which the snowfall is so thick that the ground cannot be distinguished from the sky) while returning to base camp. He was supposed to travel due north for 4.4 km, but when the snow clears, he discovers that he actually traveled 7.8 km at 47° north of due east.

(a) How far must he now travel to reach base camp?
(b) In what direction must he travel?

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on?  It would probably help you to draw a diagram.  Perhaps then you can see for youself how to solve this, or at least ask more specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how I can draw the diagram and how to approach this question. Should I be splitting this up unto components?

Answer (score 1):

This is a trigonometry question. Draw a diagram (triangle) and figure out the 3rd side length and angles. Hint: read about the [cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Answer (score 0):

First, as has been mentioned, **DRAW A DIAGRAM**!

Draw a set of x-y axes. The most usual set-up for this type of problem is that the positive x-axis is East, and the positive y-axis is North.

Mark the origin as the confused explorer's starting point. Mark his intended destination, and his actual location.

You ***can*** use vectors for this problem, and you ***should*** be splitting them up into components.

1) To achieve his goal (staying alive!) how far East and how far North ***should*** the explorer have moved from his original spot?

2)  How far East and how far North did he ***actually*** travel?

3)  How far East and how far North does he now need to travel to change each answer in 2) into the answers in 1)?